# angularjs ng-repeat not stopping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use angularJS to set up multiple links to various pages with the ng-repeat directive like so

```
<div class="talks">
    <a ng-repeat="talk in talks" ng-href="#/talk/{{ talk.id }}">
        <h5>{{ talk.speaker }}</h5>
        <h4>{{ talk.title }}</h4>

        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="360px" ng-attr-height="40px" viewBox="0 0 360 40" xml:space="preserve">
            <path ng-attr-d="{{ getPathSmall(talk, 'engagement', talk.highest, true, false) }}" stroke="#0bcea7" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" />
            <path ng-attr-d="{{ getPathSmall(talk, 'mood', talk.highest, true) }}" stroke="#1486c1" fill="none" stroke-width="2px" />
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>
```

but this loops through each talk in talks infinitely. Can ng-repeat be stopped after a single loop?

Comment: Can you show us how `talks` looks like? Are you doing anything with it in your controller?

Comment: you can actually limit the ng-repeat like so:
`<a ng-repeat="talk in talks| limitTo:1" ng-href="#/talk/{{ talk.id }}">`
but if you have infinite loop you have a problem in what you are doing, you better solve the problem than find shortcuts.
it would be easy to see the data structure you want to iterate through.

Comment: Agree that you should find a solution if it keeps looping. But you can access the first object directly instead of using ngRepeat. Use `{{talks[0].id}}` etc.

Comment: In your controller, is `$scope.talks` fetched from a remote data source, or are you building it in angular? If you're building it in angular, you probably have a bug in your code that's creating the infinite loop there.

Comment: talks is a json object consisting of fields such as Speaker, Title, start and end times. getPathSmall uses speaker, start and end times to collect data from an online api for display in the svg